# Error cloning TFS files to GIT repository

Tags: git, tfs, azure-devops

I would like to migrate my code in an on-premises TFS instance to a GIT project hosted in Visual Studio Team Services (was Visual Studio Online), keeping all the history. In order to do that, I execute the following command in the Command Prompt running as Administrator:

```
git tf clone http://[myserver]/tfs/defaultcollection $/[TFSPath] [destinationFolder] --deep
```

After a lot of time downloading things into a .git directory inside the destination folder, it fails with the error:

> Warning: The contents for the item $/[TFS path for a file] could not
>   be downloaded because you either lack read permissions or the item was
>   destroyed.

Well, I can see and open the referenced file. Therefore, the item was not destroyed and I don't lack read permissions on it.

Do you know what can I do in order to solve this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It  sounds like  there is something up with the history. Have you  tried a clone without --deep?

Answer (score 0):

`Git-TF` is a set of command line tools that facilitate the use of a local Git repository with TFS. Here is a good blog about [Migrate an existing project from TFS to Git with changeset history intact](http://chriskirby.net/blog/migrate-an-existing-project-from-tfs-to-github-with-changeset-history-intact) for you reference.

According to your error info, if you don't have the permission problem, this may be the network error. Such as your VPN drops. Try again and you can also try to not use  `--deep` option as MrHinsh mentioned to narrow down this issue.

Comment: I am running the command on the local network (not through a VPN). If I remove the --deep option, the cloning process woks, but this invalidates the migration, since I need the history on GIT.